# JavaScript Countdown Timer to specific time everyday

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently developing a website with a countdown timer at the headline: http://iphone.myhandykey.com/

The current timer is just 12hrs + few mins.. What I would like is the countdown timer will show the time remaining until 11PM on the Time Zone of the current visitor. Is that possible? Thanks!

```
Here is the JavaScript:



function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, hours, minutes, seconds;
        setInterval(function () {



        hours = parseInt(((timer / 60) / 60 ) % 60, 10);



        minutes = parseInt((timer / 60)%60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;



        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    var onehour = 60 * 600 * 1.231,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(onehour, display);
};
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<span id=time></span>
```

EDIT: If the visitor's current time is for example 11:40pm, It should display 23hrs & 20mins left..

Comment: Please share your code and try to locate the problem to your best. Then the community can do the rest.

Comment: Thank you Alex. I have added the script.

Comment: What if the user visits the page and it's already say 11:19PM local time? Display a negative clock or give them 24:41:00 to decide?

Comment: If the visitor's current time is for example 11:19pm, It should display 23hrs & 41mins left..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
(function() {
  var start = new Date;
  start.setHours(23, 0, 0); // 11pm

  function pad(num) {
    return ("0" + parseInt(num)).substr(-2);
  }

  function tick() {
    var now = new Date;
    if (now > start) { // too late, go to tomorrow
      start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
    }
    var remain = ((start - now) / 1000);
    var hh = pad((remain / 60 / 60) % 60);
    var mm = pad((remain / 60) % 60);
    var ss = pad(remain % 60);
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML =
      hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss;
    setTimeout(tick, 1000);
  }

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', tick);
})();
```

```html
Only <span id='time'></span> left!
```

Comment: @smcd please could you advise on expanding this to include a day? as in I'd like to set it to count down to the 10am on th 23rd of June 20, for example.

Comment: @Chips147 I think this will do it, keeping in the H:M:S remaining format https://jsfiddle.net/gantyev3/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var mg = new Date(2016, 5, 21, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        var tmr = window.setInterval(function () {
            var d = new Date();
            var dif = mg - d;
            var s = parseInt(dif / 1000);
if (s < 0) {
    document.getElementById('spCnt').innerHTML = 'Event starts';
    window.clearInterval(tmr);
    return;
}
            var sec = s % 60;
            var m = parseInt(s / 60);
            var min = m % 60;
            var h = parseInt(m / 60);
            var hour = h % 24;
            d = parseInt(h / 24);

            document.getElementById('spCnt').innerHTML = d + ' days ' + hour + ' hours ' + min + ' min and ' + sec + ' sec remaining';
        }, 1000);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your respond. can I get the html code?

Comment: html code? if you wish so. `<span id="spCnt"></span>`