# 24h countdown timer with progress bar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, countdown

I am working on an application to help people create new habits or discard old ones. For this application, I want to have a countdown timer which counts down every day, thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358307/javascript-countdown-timer-to-specific-time-everyday) I got this to work, the next step is to add a progress bar which counts down along with the timer (so basically 00:00 = full progress bar, 23:59 = empty progress bar).

I have been looking everywhere but I can't seem to figure it out or even get a start with it. I would like to see `#goal-time` decreasing.

I hope someone could give me some directions/hints or even some snippets if that's possible! Thanks!

```js
(function() {
  var start = new Date;
  start.setHours(24, 0, 0); //hh:mm:ss

  function pad(num) {
    return ("0" + parseInt(num)).substr(-2);
  }

  function tick() {
    var now = new Date;
    if (now > start) { // too late, go to tomorrow
      start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
    }
    var remain = ((start - now) / 1000);
    var hh = pad((remain / 60 / 60) % 60);
    var mm = pad((remain / 60) % 60);
    var ss = pad(remain % 60);
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss;
    setTimeout(tick, 1000);
  }

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', tick);
})();
```

```css
.goal-progress {
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thick;
  height: 80px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background-color: black;
}

#time {
  float: right;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

.goal-time-container {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: 115px;
}

#goal-time {
  background-color: black;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="goal-progress">
  <div id="time"></div>
  <!-- time countdown -->
  <div id="img"></div>
  <div class="goal-time-container">
    <!-- container of the progress bar -->
    <div id="goal-time"></div>
    <!-- soon to (hopefully) be progress bar -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this you can take the seconds held in the `remain` variable and use them to work out the percentage of the seconds remaining in one day, `86400`, and then set that percentage as the width of the progress bar:

```js
(function() {
  var start = new Date;
  start.setHours(24, 0, 0); //hh:mm:ss

  function pad(num) {
    return ("0" + parseInt(num)).substr(-2);
  }

  function tick() {
    var now = new Date;
    if (now > start) { // too late, go to tomorrow
      start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
    }
    var remain = ((start - now) / 1000);
    var hh = pad((remain / 60 / 60) % 60);
    var mm = pad((remain / 60) % 60);
    var ss = pad(remain % 60);
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss;
    
    // bar width calulation:
    var pc = remain * (100 / 86400);
    document.querySelector('#goal-time').style.width = pc + '%';
    
    setTimeout(tick, 1000);
  }

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', tick);
})();
```

```css
.goal-progress {
  border: 5px solid #000;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 50px 20px 20px 0;
  background-color: black;
}

#time {
  float: right;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

.goal-time-container {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: 115px;
}

#goal-time {
  background-color: black;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="goal-progress">
  <div id="time"></div>
  <div id="img"></div>
  <div class="goal-time-container">
    <div id="goal-time"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much for the quick respond!

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

You can user getTime() function to get the number of milliseconds difference b/w two dates.

eg

```js
let diff = new Date("<future_date>").getTime() - new Date().getTime();
```

You can use diff value to set the progressbar style (width or percentage or whatever).

Comment: A title "How to implement progress bar" would have been better then.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to add:

```
  const totalSeconds = 24 * 60 * 60;
```

right after:

```
start.setHours(24,0,0)
```

Then add:

```
document.getElementById('goal-time').style.width = ((remain / totalSeconds) * 100) + '%';
```

right after:

```
document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss;
```

to calculate the width of your progress bar.